# Delete function not working with controller

Tags: laravel

Hello guy's my I just wrote an delete for my project, it lookes like that:

```
public function projectdelete(Project $project)
{
    $project->delete();
    return back();
}
```

My form :

```
<form action="{{route('project.delete',$project )}}"
    method="POST" 
    onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the project?')">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::delete('/dashboard/project/create/{id}', [
    DashboardController::class, 'projectdelete'
])->name('project.delete');
```

Why is not deleting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on the parameter, your route parameter is `{id}`, on controller you are using Model Binding, for model binding your route parameter name need to be matched with your model `{project}` :

```
Route::delete('/dashboard/project/create/{project}', [
    DashboardController::class, 'projectdelete'
])->name('project.delete');
```

Comment: @m0n0l0g If you were happy that an answer has solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. You can do that by clicking the checkmark / tick underneath the score.

Answer (score 0):

In your blade file pass the project parameter as `project` and also in your `routes` give your parameter name as `project`:

**My form :**

```
<form action="{{route('project.delete', ['project' => $project])}}" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the project?')">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::delete('/dashboard/project/create/{project}', [DashboardController::class, 'projectdelete'])->name('project.delete');
```